# How do I select a particular div id which is present under another div?

Tags: jquery

I have div present under main div named as myordersdiv

**This is the HTML**

```
<div id="myordersdiv" >
   <div class="Topping-details" id="67">67</div>
   <div class="Topping-details" id="68">68</div>
</div>

$(document).on("click", "#buttonId", function(){

    $("#myordersdiv .Topping-details").show();

});
```

As per the code above  , On click of the buton , i am showing all Topping-details

My question is that how can i only display the  Topping-details that belongs to Id 68 ??

Comment: Just as an aside, you shouldn't be using the `id` attribute to store the IDs of items. Use an attribute with a `data-` prefix, e.g. `data-id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the id instead

```
$("#myordersdiv #68").show();
```

Note than an id of 68 *may* cause issues with it being just a number.

(My fiddle suggests it does work with just a number - http://jsfiddle.net/93G8c/ - but still, best not if you don't have to!)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myordersdiv .Topping-details#68").show();
```

Notice the selector has `#68` at the end, which tells jQuery to select the element with class `.Topping-details` and an id of `68`.

I would definitely use more-specific IDs rather than numbers, for example `topping-68` would be much better. The reason is that IDs should be unique to the document and the number "68" may be used elsewhere. A bit pedantic, but important none the less.